# Using different sized typefaces for roman and italic texts in the same paragraph

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, typeface

I've been trying to use Inter typeface for all texts in my site except for the links and italics, that will use another typeface –still deciding which one–.

The problem is that I think I need to find a font that has the same x-height because every time I use any other sized font, things get messy and I need something like:

```
em {
  font-family: "different-typeface";
  zoom: 130%;
  line-height: .8; 
}
```

And that's the code that is making things ugly. I'm no web developer, but I'm trying to learn something beyond my graphic design skills.

Is there any walkaround to solve this? Thank you all!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `zoom: 130%` for `<em>` and `<a>` have you tried tweaking `font-size` for both to see if that gets you closer?

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Shawshank37927/e1c5L4v9/24/)

Something to keep in mind is that `zoom` was used as an IE hack back in the day and is deprecated now.

Comment: That would only solve size for one element, p, h1, or anything else. That’s why I used zoom, to always be a % of the other font’s size. It would still with mess the line-height.

Comment: But if the properties (size, line height, etc.) of `<p>` are set, then you can tweak those same properties for the child `<em>` element where needed, right? Sure, it's not solved in one swoop, but you can still adjust those properties to dovetail your different font types.

Comment: I guess that could work. I must see where the second font could appear and then tweak the font-size and line-height there. I wish there could be a simpler way... Thanks!